# Python: Unable to open and read a file

Tags: python

I am totally new to python.
I was trying to read a file which I already created but getting the below error

```
File "C:/Python25/Test scripts/Readfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    filename = open('C:\Python25\Test scripts\newfile','r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python25\\Test scripts\newfile
```

My code:

```
filename = open('C:\Python25\Test scripts\newfile','r')
print filename.read()
```

Also I tried

```
filename = open('C:\\Python25\\Test scripts\\newfile','r')
print filename.read()
```

But same errors I am getting.

Comment: Does `newfile` have an extension (such as `.txt`)?

Comment: I would add the .txt extension plus I would delete the space between Test and scripts and replace it with an underscore (i.e., rename that directory, if it indeed has a space).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fpath = r'C:\Python25\Test scripts\newfile'
if not os.path.exists(fpath):
  print 'File does not exist'
  return

with open(fpath, 'r') as src:
  src.read()
```

First you validate that file, that it exists.
Then you open it. With wrapper is more usefull, it closes your file, after you finish reading. So you will not stuck with many open descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably having this issue because you didn't include the full filename.

You should try:

```
filename = open('C:\Python25\Test scripts\newfile.txt','r')
print filename.read()
```

*Also if you're running this python file in the same location as the target file your are opening, you don't need to give the full directory, you can just call:

```
filename = open(newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's how I got it right.

your code:

```
filename = open('C:\\Python25\\Test scripts\\newfile','r')
print filename.read()
```

Try this:

```
with open('C:\\Python25\\Test scripts\\newfile') as myfile:
print(myfile.read())
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS code. If I am not using dent it would not work for the print line. So try to have the format right then you will see the magic.

```
with open("mytest.txt") as myfile:
    print(myfile.read())
```

or without format like this:

```
hellofile=open('mytest.txt', 'r')
print(hellofile.read())
```